# How to disable joomla k2 word limit for introtext

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

The website I'm working on uses component K2 for Joomla 2.5. I need to display images from introtexts on category page with list of its articles but images don't appear because of word limit filter. How can I disable this only for K2 introtext? [not in global parameters of Joomla]

Comment: This question is about Joomla extensions, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: As far as I know there is no "word limit" filter on K2 introtexts. I think that limit is imposed by your template (and not by K2). Check your template files (displaying "item lists") and see if you find the problem there.